# Search running programs - Command-Space or Spotlight equivalent in Windows

Tags: windows

After coming back to Windows after using a Mac for a while, I got used to using Spotlight to open running programs by hitting <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and typing the name of the program and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to focus that program window. I find this is often easier than other focus methods.

For some things <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Cortana) or just <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> (Search) will open an existing window, but for example, OneNote opens a new copy of the program.

Are there built in methods in Windows, or third-party programs to quickly search running programs with text?

Comment: Does the `Applications` tab in the `Task Manager` not give what you're looking for? Or are you looking for an exact replacement?

Comment: More of an exact replacement as it is direct and fast to switch programs without leaving the keyboard. It also uses the program name, which is often what I am thinking inside my head, instead of window order, location etc like "Windows + Tab" or "Alt + Tab".

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @mrdavenz not yet.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shortcut windows + S , that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, this shortcut opens the general windows search function. The original question was how to quickly focus onto already running programs by typing their name.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is provided by [PowerToys Run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run) as it allows to do most of the same things you can with Spotlight (like opening apps, switching to their active windows, searching the web, performing calculations & more; also, it respects dark/light mode set in your system):
[image: screenshot of PowerToys Run search in dark mode]

Neat thing is that it uses `Alt + Space` shortcut by default which happens to be the same in terms of muscle memory as with Spotlight.

It is part of PowerToys utilities for which installation guide is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install).

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is [Wox](http://www.wox.one/). Built using python and uses [Everything.exe](https://www.voidtools.com/) to search the file system.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.